# How to get the native Georgian characters like ('რატი') using Openrowset in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode

How to get the native Georgian characters using Openrowset in SQL?
The text file ('D:\html.txt') contains only one word ('რატი'). Every time I run the following code with all possible variations (SINGLE_CLOB|SINGLE_NCLOB,  CODEPAGE =ACP|OEM|RAW|code_page), as a result I get "áƒ áƒáƒ¢áƒ˜":

```
SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET (BULK N'D:\html.txt', SINGLE_CLOB,CODEPAGE = '65001' ) as myfile
```

I checked all relevant posts, but none of them solves this problem.

Comment: The [openrowset] Tag looks as if you are using MS [sql-server]?

Comment: It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python): `print('რატი'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252', 'backslashreplace'))` returns `áƒ áƒ\x90áƒ¢áƒ˜`

Comment: Yes, Stefan, I am using MS SQL Server

Comment: It could be that SSMS just isn't showing them properly. I suggest using `UNICODE` (and `LEFT`) to inspect the value for the first character. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/unicode-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15